# Running init.d script produces "start-stop-daemon: not found"

Tags: debian, sysvinit, start-stop-daemon

I try to start monit using:

```
/etc/init.d/monit start
```

I then get the error:

```
[....] Starting daemon monitor: monit/etc/init.d/monit: 124: /etc/init.d/monit: start-stop-daemon: not found
failed!
```

Typing

```
which start-stop-daemon
```

shows

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon
```

ls -al in /sbin shows

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     26740 Jan 21 12:18 start-stop-daemon
```

edit: adding script

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          monit
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs
# Should-Start:      $all
# Should-Stop:       $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: service and resource monitoring daemon
# Description:       monit is a utility for managing and monitoring
#                    processes, programs, files, directories and filesystems
#                    on a Unix system. Monit conducts automatic maintenance
#                    and repair and can execute meaningful causal actions
#                    in error situations.
### END INIT INFO

set -e

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

DAEMON=/usr/bin/monit
CONFIG="/etc/monit/monitrc"
DELAY="/etc/monit/monit_delay"
NAME=monit
DESC="daemon monitor"
MONIT_OPTS=
PID="/var/run/$NAME.pid"

# Check if DAEMON binary exist
[ -f $DAEMON ] || exit 0

[ -f "/etc/default/$NAME" ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# For backward compatibility, handle startup variable:
if [ -n "$startup" ]
then
  if [ "$1" = "start" ]
  then
    printf "\tPlease, use START variable in /etc/default/monit\n"
    printf "\tto enable/disable $NAME startup.\n"
  fi

  if [ -z "$START" ] && [ "$startup" -eq 1 ]
  then
    START="yes"
  fi
fi

# For backward compatibility, handle CHECK_INTERVALS variable:
if [ -n "$CHECK_INTERVALS" ]
then
  if [ "$1" = "start" ]
  then
    printf "\tPlease, use MONIT_OPTS variable in /etc/default/monit\n"
    printf "\tto specify command line options for $NAME.\n"
  fi

  MONIT_OPTS="$MONIT_OPTS -d $CHECK_INTERVALS"
fi

MONIT_OPTS="-c $CONFIG $MONIT_OPTS"

monit_not_configured () {
  if [ "$1" != "stop" ]
  then
    printf "\tplease configure $NAME and then edit /etc/default/$NAME\n"
    printf "\tand set the \"START\" variable to \"yes\" in order to allow\n"
    printf "\t$NAME to start\n"
  fi
  exit 0
}

monit_check_config () {
  # Check for emtpy config.
  if [ "`grep -s -v \"^#\" $CONFIG`" = "" ]
  then
    echo "empty config, please edit $CONFIG."
    exit 0
  fi
}

monit_check_perms () {
  # Check the permission on configfile.
  # The permission must not have more than -rwx------ (0700) permissions.

  # Skip checking, fix perms instead.
  /bin/chmod go-rwx $CONFIG
}

monit_delayed_monitoring () {
  if [ -f $DELAY ]
  then
    printf "Warning: Please, set start delay for $NAME in config file\n"
    printf "         and delete $DELAY file.\n"

    if [ ! -x $DELAY ]
    then
      printf "Warning: A delayed start file exists ($DELAY)\n"
      printf "         but it is not executable.\n"
    else
      $DELAY &
    fi
  fi
}

monit_checks () {
  # Check if START variable is set to "yes", if not we exit.
  if [ "$START" != "yes" ]
  then
    monit_not_configured $1
  fi
  # Check for emtpy configfile
  monit_check_config
  # Check permissions of configfile
  monit_check_perms
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    monit_checks $1
    if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo \
                         --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON \
                         -- $MONIT_OPTS
    then
      log_end_msg 0
    else
      log_end_msg 1
    fi
    monit_delayed_monitoring
    ;;
  stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    if start-stop-daemon --retry TERM/5/KILL/5 --oknodo --stop --quiet \
                         --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON
    then
      log_end_msg 0
    else
      log_end_msg 1
    fi
    ;;
  reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC configuration" "$NAME"
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet \
                                --oknodo --pidfile $PID \
                                --exec $DAEMON -- $MONIT_OPTS
    then
      log_end_msg 0
    else
      log_end_msg 1
    fi
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
  syntax)
    $DAEMON $MONIT_OPTS -t
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc -p $PID $DAEMON $NAME
    ;;
  *)
    log_action_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload|syntax|status}"
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Perhaps they should specify the full path in the init script.

Comment: I faced a similar problem with the Live version of Squeeze before. Is this Debian Live by any chance?

Comment: Are you trying to run `/etc/init.d/monit start` as root?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I'm not using Live, it's a proper install running from a VPS. I am running it as root, yes.

Comment: Try putting `echo $PATH; exit` at the top of the script, run it, and tell me the output.

Comment: Hi, it says: /etc/init.d/monit: line 1: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: Strange, I can't figure out what's happening, but remove  `echo $PATH; exit` from the script, and then replace `start-stop-daemon` with `/sbin/start-stop-daemon` in the line 124.

Comment: Hi, now it says:  [....] Starting daemon monitor: monit/etc/init.d/monit: 124: /etc/init.d/monit: /sbin/start-stop-daemon: not found
 failed!
Thanks.

Comment: The fact that `echo $PATH; exit` gave you a strange error means some serious problem with your script. No problems with unprintable characters? Are the end-of-lines correct?

Comment: Complementing what vinc17 said, run `file /etc/init.d/monit`.

Comment: It looks like `echo $PATH` was executed as `$PATH` (i.e. the contents of `$PATH` being the command, as in this case with bash, one gets the error message you obtained).

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies. I ran file <filename>, and it says:    /etc/init.d/monit: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable

Comment: Could you try again with `echo $PATH; exit` at the beginning of the script? If you still get the error, can you put the beginning of the output of `hd /etc/init.d/monit` (one must see everything at least until the `exit`).

Comment: Looking at your initial error message `[....] Starting daemon monitor: monit/etc/init.d/monit: 124: /etc/init.d/monit: start-stop-daemon: not found failed!`, it appears that `start-stop-daemon` is executed successfully, but it tries to execute the command `monit/etc/init.d/monit: 124: /etc/init.d/monit: start-stop-daemon: not found` (I don't know why), which obviously doesn't exist, hence the error message `Starting daemon monitor: ... failed!`.

Comment: @vinc17 From my tests, it seems it is just a newline missing after the message `Starting daemon monitor: monit`

Comment: @TeresaeJunior The missing newline is normal: `start-stop-daemon` waits for the command to terminate, then it should write `OK` or `FAIL` in `[....]`. Since this must be done on the same line, a newline is not output before that.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior OK, just `/etc/init.d/monit: 124: /etc/init.d/monit: start-stop-daemon: not found` comes from the `start-stop-daemon` line. The error on `echo $PATH` suggests that `/bin/sh` is bash, not dash. But the error on `start-stop-daemon` seems to come from dash. In such a case, the executed command seems to be `/etc/init.d/monit: start-stop-daemon`, which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. Was very late here in the uk :) i re-added the line at the top as advised, no error this time just `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`  `hd /etc/init.d/monit` shows `00000000  65 63 68 6f 20 24 50 41  54 48 3b 20 65 78 69 74  |echo $PATH; exit|` on the first line. Thanks!

Comment: @JonS So, the cause of the error is that your `$PATH` doesn't contain `/sbin`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I've added sbin to the path: `echo $PATH;
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin` but I now get: `[....] Starting daemon monitor: monit/etc/init.d/monit: 124: /etc/init.d/monit: start-stop-daemon: not found
 failed!`  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

On Debian 7 I had a similar error: `daemon: not found`

And I was able to fix it with:

```
apt-get install daemon
```

Comment: I also tried on Debian 8 (Jessie) and it worked as a charm!

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure to add `PATH` to your script and that it includes `/sbin`. Since the `init` script won't share the `PATH` environment variable with the rest of the system you need to set it directly on your script and make sure `/sbin` is in there, for example, add:

   ```
    PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
   ```

   At the beginning of your script.
2. Debug your script to make sure start-stop-daemon is reading the path of monit correctly from the `DAEMON` variable. In order to do that add the following line at the beginning of your script:

   ```
   set -x #echo on
   ```

   The whole thing would look like

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   set -x #echo on
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides:          monit
   # Required-Start:    $remote_fs
   # Required-Stop:     $remote_fs
   # Should-Start:      $all
   # Should-Stop:       $all
   # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
   # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
   # Short-Description: service and resource monitoring daemon
   # Description:       monit is a utility for managing and monitoring
   #                    processes, programs, files, directories and filesystems
   #                    on a Unix system. Monit conducts automatic maintenance
   #                    and repair and can execute meaningful causal actions
   #                    in error situations.
   ### END INIT INFO

   set -e

   PATH=/sbin:/rest of your path here.
   ```

   Your script.

   If `DAEMON` is corrupted somehow try surrounding it with parenthesis:

   ```
   if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo \
                        --pidfile $PID --exec $($DAEMON) \
                        -- $MONIT_OPTS
   ```

   Or simply add the path to the binary directly.

   ```
       if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo \
                            --pidfile $PID --exec /usr/bin/monit \
                            -- $MONIT_OPTS
   ```
3. If the last option doesn't work then make sure the binary is actually there. If it is then you will have to check if start-stop-daemon is actually permitted to access it. Look into chrooting.

Answer (score 0):

glad, you could fix it with `apt-get install deamon`

in my case it was a missing link from: `/bin/busybox` to `/sbin/start-stop-daemon`

```
cd /sbin
ln -s ../bin/busybox start-stop-daemon
```

that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora or RedHat based system you need to install dpkg as compatibility layer with debian based distribution. `start-stop-daemon` is provided by dpkg.

```
sudo dnf install dpkg
```

on Fedora 33

Comment: they are already talking about debian. about debian sqeeze which is nearly ten years old

Comment: On gentoo, installing dpkg does not fix this error for me.